# Kendo UI grid - batch update not executed

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm implementing a simple (at least ,that was the goal) Kendo UI grid that displays two columns: one holding a checkbox, bound to a boolean, and one holding a display name for the item. The `checkbox` column has a simple template, and the `change()` `event` of the `checkbox` is handled so that the `model` in the `datasource` gets updated. I have verified this, and it works.

The data source has been configured for `batch`, and defines a `transport` for `read` and `update`. Both call a function that perform the ajax call. As I said before, the `read` function is handled as expected. However, the `update` function defined on the `transport` is not. The `sync()` on the datasource is triggered with a simple button whose `click` event is hooked to a function that calls `datasource.sync()` (or `grid.saveChanges()`).

```
transport: {
            read: function(options) {
                return loadStuff(options);
            },
            update: function (options) {
                return updateStuff(options);
            }
}
```

When debugging in the Kendo UI code, it looks like the models attribute on the ModelSet is always empty, and therefore the `sync()` decides that there's nothing to sync. Anyone got a clue what is happening here?

**UPDATE:**
Looks like something may be wrong when handling the checkbox `check` / `uncheck`. Apparently I should use something like

```
$('#divGrid').on('click', '.chkbx', function() {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    var grid = $('#divGrid').data().kendoGrid;
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
    dataItem.set("Selected", checked);
});
```

Unfortunately, it looks like the `set()` method is not defined on the data item. When debugging, it only contains the `data`, and no Model object having the `set()` method.

**UPDATE 2:**
Tried wrapping the data returned from the ajax call in a model defined with `Model.define()`. That seems to solve the issue of the model not being dirty, as the _modified property on the model returns `true`. However, the models array in the ModelSet remains empty. Is this a bug in Kendo UI, or am I going the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to `bind` to `click` event on the `checkboxes`.

I´ve posted an example on using it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/AtjD6/1/) where you can see it running. This example displays in a grid two columns: first text (tick) and second boolean rendered as a checkbox (selected); the update is batch (so, it's pretty close to what you have).

Questions to keep in mind are:

For displaying the checkbox while not in edit mode, you should define a template, something like this. You might realize that the checkbox is in `disabled` state by default since you want to edit it as other fields (selecting the cell first). This also guarantees that the model is correctly updated:

```
{
    field   : "selected",
    title   : "Selected",
    template: "<input type='checkbox' name='selected' #= selected ? 'checked' : '' # disabled/>"
}
```

Define in the model that this field is boolean:

```
schema   : {
    id   : "id",
    model: {
        fields: {
            symbol  : { type: "string" },
            selected: { type: "boolean" }
        }
    }
},
```

Define the `transport.update` function, something like:

```
transport: {
    read  : function (operation) {
        // Your function for reading
    },
    update: function (operation) {
        // Display modified data in an alert
        alert("update" + JSON.stringify(operation.data.models, null, 4));
        // Invoke updating function
        // that should ends with an operation.success(the_new_data)
        // In this example just say ok
        operation.success(operation.data.models)
    }
}
```

*EDIT*: If you want to be able to modify the `checkbox` state without having to enter in `edit` mode first, you should:

Remove the `disabled` from the template:

```
{
    field     : "selected",
    title     : "Selected",
    template  : "<input type='checkbox' name='selected' #= selected ? 'checked' : '' #/>"
},
```

Then bind the `click` event on checkboxes to the following handler function:

```
$("#stocks_tbl").on("click", "input:checkbox", function(ev) {
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
    dataItem.set("selected", this.checked);
});
```

Where `#stocks_tbl` is the `id` of the `div` that contains the `grid`. You might see it running [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/AtjD6/2/).

**NOTE**: It's important the `on` with the three parameters for making it [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the sample. While I did register on the click event and apparently did not need to, I did manage to get about as far as your example goes. The problem that both my and your sample still have, is that you first have to click in the cell that contains the checkbox, before you can edit the checkbox. If you don't disable the checkbox on screen initialization, the model does not seem to get updated appropriately. I need to find out how to eliminate that first click ...

Comment: Please, see **EDIT** for being able of modifying the checkbox without entering the edit mode.

Comment: That's a great answer from OnaBai, and he should be given credit.  I spent a long time trying to get this to work and the solution is not clear from Telerik.  I should add that the "click" JS won't work unless you have already declared the "grid" object.   In my case, this works: `var dataItem = $('#stocks_tbl').data('kendoGrid').dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));`